# Javascript does not work upon AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page which does an AJAX call and loads an entire page. The page that gets loaded has some Javascript. The javascript works on page by itself when loaded, but when its gets loaded by AJAX, the Javascript does not work. I dont know what I am missing.

**The code of the loaded page**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
if(name=='lstbox')document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
else document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
}

function hidefield() {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
}

</script>

<head>
</head>
<body onload="hidefield()">
<form action = "test2.php" method = "post">

Please enter a name for the App <input type = "text" name = "name">

<table border = "1"><tr><th>Choose a Label</th><th>Choose an element</th></tr>

<tr><td><input type = "text" name = "label1" /></td> <td> 

<select name = "elementtype1" id="elementtype1" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

<option value = 'select'> Select </option>

<option value='txtbox'>Text Box</option>

<option value='lstbox'>List Box</option>

<option value='chkbox'>Check Box</option>

<option value='radio'>Radio Button</option>

</select></td><td><div id="div1">Enter Listbox options: <input type="text" name="whatever1" /></div></td></tr>

</table>

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**The code of the loading(AJAX) page is**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="responseHTML.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="storage" style="display:none;">
</div>

<div id="displayed">



<FORM name="ajax" method="POST" action="">
    <p>

    <INPUT type="BUTTON" value="Get the Panel"  ONCLICK="loadWholePage('appcreator.php')">

    </p>

</FORM>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**The ajax.js code**

```
function createXHR() 
{
    var request = false;
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (err3) {
        try {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (err1) 
        {
            request = false;
        }
            }
        }
    return request;
}
```

**The responseHTML.js code**

```
function getBody(content) 
{
   test = content.toLowerCase();    // to eliminate case sensitivity
   var x = test.indexOf("<body");
   if(x == -1) return "";

   x = test.indexOf(">", x);
   if(x == -1) return "";

   var y = test.lastIndexOf("</body>");
   if(y == -1) y = test.lastIndexOf("</html>");
   if(y == -1) y = content.length;    // If no HTML then just grab everything till end

   return content.slice(x + 1, y);   
} 

/**
    Loads a HTML page
    Put the content of the body tag into the current page.
    Arguments:
        url of the other HTML page to load
        id of the tag that has to hold the content
*/      

function loadHTML(url, fun, storage, param)
{
    var xhr = createXHR();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    { 
        if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //if(xhr.status == 200)
            {
                storage.innerHTML = getBody(xhr.responseText);
                fun(storage, param);
            }
        } 
    }; 

    xhr.open("GET", url , true);
    xhr.send(null); 

} 

    /**
        Callback
        Assign directly a tag
    */      


    function processHTML(temp, target)
    {
        target.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
    }

    function loadWholePage(url)
    {
        var y = document.getElementById("storage");
        var x = document.getElementById("displayed");
        loadHTML(url, processHTML, x, y);
    }   


    /**
        Create responseHTML
        for acces by DOM's methods
    */  

    function processByDOM(responseHTML, target)
    {
        target.innerHTML = "Extracted by id:<br />";

        // does not work with Chrome/Safari
        //var message = responseHTML.getElementsByTagName("div").namedItem("two").innerHTML;
        var message = responseHTML.getElementsByTagName("div").item(1).innerHTML;

        target.innerHTML += message;

        target.innerHTML += "<br />Extracted by name:<br />";

        message = responseHTML.getElementsByTagName("form").item(0);
        target.innerHTML += message.dyn.value;
    }

    function accessByDOM(url)
    {
        //var responseHTML = document.createElement("body");    // Bad for opera
        var responseHTML = document.getElementById("storage");
        var y = document.getElementById("displayed");
        loadHTML(url, processByDOM, responseHTML, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is outside the body tag, and the loader picks out only the code inside the body tag, so the script is not even part of what you add to the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how do I go about now. I need to make it work upon AJAx call

Comment: @user702813: Just as you extract the content of the body tag, you would have to extract the content of the script tag, create a new script element, put the script into it and add the element to the head element.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript loaded in HTML through AJAX will not be executed.

If you want to include scripts dynamically, append `<script>` tags to the existing loaded page's `<head>` element.

Answer (score 2):

execute the script with jquery rather than with innerHTML

```
//this is not working! 
document.getElementById("chart-content").innerHTML = this.responseText;

//try this
$("#chart-content").html(this.responseText);
```

Comment: Thank you I've been search for a solution that will work with my internal js script for almost 2 days now

Answer (score 0):

Loading you Js within the `<head>` should work. use this.

```
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadJs);
} else {
    loadJs();
}

function loadJs() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/assets/script/editor-controlls.js';
    script.defer = true
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```